# Set module /blog as homepage

Tags: magento2, redirect, nginx, blog

I am trying to set the AheadWorks blog module as homepage of Magento 2 for a site. So user gets directly to domain.com/blog instead of **domain.com**. Is it possible in the admin or Nginx somehow?

Comment: Write 301 redirection in .htaccess

Comment: I use nginx. Dont have .htaccess

Comment: Oh ok can u help with the correct code for redirect?

Comment: nginx dont care about .htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it this way:

Configuration —->>> general —->> web

Default url = changed value from cms to aw_blog

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

You can add it in the /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file

add the below code to it

```
server {

listen 80
listen 443;

server_name blog.club.in;

location = / {
    return 301 http://domain.com/blog;
}
}
```

> NOTE : Make sure you choose to move this temporarily or permanent.  Temporary in the sense use **302** instead of **301**

[Visit this link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-temporary-and-permanent-redirects-with-nginx) for more information and multi domain configuration as well.

Hope this helps.

Comment: the question about nginx , not apache, there is nothing to do with .htaccess

Comment: you return every request, not redirecting to /blog.